# Svn result to batch file variable

Tags: batch-file, svn, command-line

I need to create a batch file with SVN commands based on return codes i need to do certain actions.
asume dummy_file donot exist
example:

svn delete dummy_file
if (error code == something){
do x
}else {
do y
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Exit Codes of subversion client](https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=375149)

> The "svn" command-line tool doesn't return much specific info in the exit code, just "0 == worked" / "1 == failed"

Comment: Lazy Badger Thank you very much for the worthy answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the output into a file, and then check this file to understand the command result and do what you have to do... what do you think?

```
 svn delete test > svn.out
```